# Alter menu link for taxonomy link

Tags: routes

I've path alias and taxonomy menu. Now menu displays taxonomy link as **vocabulary_name/term_name.**

For example, my vocabulary name is 'category'. I want to change into 'article'. I've to only for this situation. I've used path alias. Unfortunately my view link looks like same.

I've tired hook_menu_alter() and hook_menu_link_alter(). But there is no luck. I need your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the path alias, set your path to what you want, then from `admin/config/search/path/delete_bulk` delete all taxonomy path , then from `admin/config/search/path/udate_bulk` rebuild them.(this is is [pathauto mdoule](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto))if your menu link not worked rebuild them ( with taxonomy menu module)

Comment: For my requirements, i can't use pathauto. because i've already used.

Comment: @Guru I know you use it, I tell you rebuild your path

Comment: In my cases, i've to change term path only on main_menu

Comment: we have 2 section, one links in main menu, second path alias of node,
you should change both part

Comment: I already used path alias for [vocabulary_name][term_name]. So that page is good. I want to change only links displayed in main_menu